# Maximize variable x and minimize variable y

Tags: algorithm, numpy

I could frame it like this. A bunch of people enter a pool willing to fund something. They can offer the funds at whatever interest rate they think is right. So basically they make bids. I want to find the best and cheapest route to fund the money that was required by the guy who created the pool. I want maximum funds and minimum interest rate while also minimizing the total number of people the guy will have to pay back to

Comment: Please show the [code you have so far](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). Include at least an outline, but preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: cannot share the code

Comment: @sachin even if you cannot share the code for whatever reason: you should be able to come up with a toy example that makes clear what you exactly want

Comment: You can only maximize or minimize one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 different things you are trying to maximize/minimize. You can use weighting variables to determine what is most important to your case.
Suppose α is the importance you want to put on total capital. β is the weight you want to put on the number of lenders. α & β are subject to the constraint α + β ≤ 1.

A general formula to maximize your pool (where positive numbers are desirable) is:

Result = α*(funds)+β*(-lenders)+(1-α-β)*(-interest rate)

The positive numbers wouldn't be apples to apples comparisons unless you normalized the funds, lenders, and interest rate values.